# Android DriverManager.getConnection doesn't output errors

Tags: android

I'm trying to connect to a remote database in an Android project and it's failing to resolve the connection to my database, however I cannot see *any* information on why it failed or what's happening - the application doesn't crash, the rest of my method just doesn't complete.

How can I debug the failed connection?

Answer (score 1):

The Android SQLException reference docs are [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/sql/SQLException.html).
Some good try/catch SQLException examples [here](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/android.database.SQLException).